# Self Hosted Iron Worker Alternative

Tags: php, background, laravel, worker, digital-ocean

I now have a fully functional Iron Worker script and implemented it into my application and everything is awesome except one thing. I started to notice that my App is starting to gain some users and that Iron Worker is way to expensive for what I do with it.

So, my plan is now, deploy a couple of Digital Ocean droplets with IronWorker like software on them so I can run my scripts there.

The reason I think IronWorker isn't really suited for my goal is because the CPU usage and RAM usage of my script is really really low. I did the maths and it would save me 200 dollars a month switching from IronWorker to a self hosted Iron Worker like setup. Now, my question is, since I don't want to reinvent the wheel again, could you guys recommend some of these Iron Worker like applications that I can install on my DO Droplets and let them do their thing. It may be worth noting that I'm using Laravel 4 as my Apps framework so I have composer and all of Laravels functions and libraries available.

It may also be worth pointing out that my script takes 60 minutes to complete. And the script needs to be started when a user commands it to. There may be a delay of maximum 2-5 minutes. No more, otherwise the app would be kind of useless.

Thanks in advance for those who read this long, boring and badly structured message and thinking about it for a moment or two. :)

Comment: I could add that it would be more fortunate if a new process could be created that would be running forever until the user stops it. That is also an idea instead of stopping and starting the same job over and over again.

Comment: I know it's a few years later, but maybe this will help someone... if you don't like the idea of having a "job" running all the time, then you can consider running a bash script on an infinite loop (sleep X seconds in a while loop). If you learn bash scripting (not too hard), you can use this as an option. Take a look: [Alternatives to Cron](http://askubuntu.com/questions/525834/alternatives-to-cron)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used beanstalkd with Laravel 4 successfully have a look:

http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/download.html

Comment: I read something like that yes. Could you explain to me, how to implement this into my Application? Like modify the script so it can be ran by Laravel and Beanstalk?

Comment: Are there alternatives to Beanstalkd or is the only app around?

Comment: Thats the only one you can run yourself on your server that I have come across. If you come across others let me know :-)

Comment: Ok, I'll :). I don't really like Beanstalkd since I used it in the past and had a lot of troubles with it.